# Simple ajax error driving me crazy

Tags: html, ajax

I am simply trying to read a html file inside a div, now it is not working therefore I tried to read just a a simple text file named a.txt, the text file contains 3 lines "asdasdas" something like that.

It just won't work, the function is being called after pressing a paragraph tag, here is the code:

```
functionNew()
{       
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("divfull").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","a.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

any ideas why its not working?

Comment: try putting the full path to your file, e.g. http://thing.com/a.txt

Comment: It's on my computer..
The error that I'm getting with firebug is syntex error

Comment: ok, which line is it pointing to?

Comment: syntax error
 

asdasdsad

a.txt (line 1, col 1)

Comment: possible problem with xmlhttp being a local variable. It may have gone out of scope by the time you get a reply back. Although not sure why you'd get a syntax error...

Comment: try console.log(xmlhttp.open); to make sure that the function exists

Answer (score 0):

code seem to be proper but try calling

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","a.txt",true);
```

before

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
```

try and let us know if it work for you