# reading text file inside a div with ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I am simply trying to read a html file inside a div, now it is not working therefore I tried to read just a a simple text file named a.txt, the text file contains 3 lines "asdasdas" something like that.

It just won't work, the function is being called after pressing a paragraph tag, here is the code:

```
function New()
{       
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("divfull").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","a.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: with firebug I get this error:
syntax error asdasdsad a.txt (line 1, col 1)

Comment: I don't get it, why it gives me syntex error...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple ajax error driving me crazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833494/simple-ajax-error-driving-me-crazy)

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you get the syntax error?

Try using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get'
    url: '', //LOCATION OF TEXT FILE
    success: function(data) {
        $('#divfull').html(data);
    }
});
```

Since its jQuery it will take care of the browser type (so you won't have to create an ActiveXObject for older IE versions). Plus, its fewer lines of code.